# bash3 process redirection file descriptor disappears when running other processes

Tags: bash, macos, io-redirection

I'm having a problem using bash redirection file descriptors with bash v3 (running on stock OSX that's what you get)

This script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo $1 >> $1
  echo A >> $1
  echo B >> $1
  /bin/echo C >> $1
  echo D >> $1
}
bar() {
  ls -l $1
  ls -l $1
}
foo >(cat -n)
bar >(cat -n)
```

produces this output

```
./x: line 7: 1: Bad file descriptor
     1  /dev/fd/63
     2  A
     3  B
     4  C
prw-rw----  0 vitaly  staff  0 Dec  7 19:58 /dev/fd/63
ls: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor
```

so as long as I use internal `echo` it works, and I can run the external `/bin/echo` **once**, then the descriptor disappears. also see how 1st invocation of ls can see it but not the 2nd one.

UPDATE for @tripleee. Can't get formatting in a comment.

There is no double redirection as far as I see.
This: `foo >(cat -n)` indeed runs `cat` in a subprocess, and connects it's `stdin` to a pipe. but it does not redirect the std in or out of `foo`, it just gets the name of the pipe as an argument. that's all.

the following script:

```
foo() {
  echo INTO PIPE: $1 >> $1
  echo this is STDOUT
  echo PIPE AGAIN >> $1
  echo STDOUT AGAIN
}
foo >(cat -n)
```

produces:

```
this is STDOUT
STDOUT AGAIN
     1  INTO PIPE: /dev/fd/63
     2  PIPE AGAIN
```

Comment: [Just speculating here...] Remember that the operating system closes the descriptors open for a process when the process exits. Since the "normal" `echo` command is built-in they are running as part of the Bash main process, and the descriptors will be kept open. But the external `/bin/echo` command is run as a new process, and when it exits the descriptor is closed. So for the last internal `echo` command the descriptor is invalid. Same when invoking the `ls` commands.

Comment: There were some bugs and problems with the lifetime of `>(...)`, many in bash3 and also in bash4. It looks like one of those bugs. If you work with an older bash, unless you are sure that `>(..)` will live properly, I suggest not to use it.

Comment: Try: `foo() { {   ....  } > "$1"; }; foo >(cat -n)`. Also try deleting _all the newlines_. It may sound funny, but I think I remember a case where the lifetime of `>(...)` ended when a newline was encountered.